# Add a file to dictionary with key and values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file that I want to read from and it is like this:

```
Warner, Bros, The Matrix, 5, 2.99

Sony, The Hobbit, 10, 3.99

Warner, Bros, Dark Knight, 4.99
```

I want to create a dictionary from that file with warner bros as key and all the others a values. I also need to join all the warner bros together to make one key and different values of the key would be the name of the movie and the quantity(5 for the matrix) and the price.

The way I am doing this is I read the file and then put everything into a List then use that list to create a dictionary, but I realized that I will have multiple keys for the same brand; for example Warner Bros. How can I make sure that I only have one brand with multiple values?

Thanks!

Comment: Make the value a list? `{"Warner bros": [{"title": "the matrix", ...}, ...], ...}`

Comment: Ok, I can do that but then how do I make all the same keys into the one key and not have duplicate keys?

Comment: thats what my answer does ...

Comment: ok, I a going to try it and let you know if it works!

Comment: I don't think you understand what a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) does in python (or any language for that matter). Start there and then you'll be able to understand @JoranBeasley's answer.

Comment: ok, I think I do understand what a dictionary is. It has a key and assign to those keys are the values which can be anything. right?

Answer (score 3):

use a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for key,value  in ([1,2],[3,4],[1,3],[4,2],[3,2]):
   d[key].append(value)
print d
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did there?

Comment: I used a default dict which initializes the keys for you so that each key is automatically a list ... then instead of setting it equal to the value you simply append it

Comment: you are going to have a very hard time splitting your string data if there are comma's other than the separators ... (eg `Warner, bros`)

Comment: I do have commas, can I just use a if statement and if it is a comma I don't append it to a dict?

Comment: @user3459811  You have an inconsistent number of columns in your text file (where a column is defined as the space between a comma). You cannot easily parse arbitrary data like that. You'll need to know more about it in order to be able to generically parse it. Or you need to already know what is on each line (at which point what is the point of the file?)

Comment: The point of the program is to read the file which contains things in this order (Company,Movie title, inventory, price) and add it to a dictionary file which you can use to add or delete the inventory or change the price.

Comment: can you guarantee there are no comma's in either the studio name or the movie title or (ideally) both?  I think you are missing some fundamental concepts or data ... why dont you post the code you use to create the current dictionary, without that I dont think I can help you anymore without just doing your assignment/task for you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
data = '''Warner, Bros, The Matrix, 5, 2.99
Sony, The Hobbit, 10, 3.99
Warner, Bros, Dark Knight, 1, 4.99''' # the 1 is missing from your example
                                      # is it a typo? or the text data has this kind
                                      # of errors that you should check?

                                      # you can read your data with a csv.reader
                                      # for this example I'll just split the lines

yourdata = dict() # or use the defaultdict approach

lines = data.split('\n')
for l in lines:
    fields = l.split(',')
    price = float(fields.pop(-1))
    quantity = int(fields.pop(-1))
    title = fields.pop(-1).strip()
    value = {'title': title, 'quantity': quantity, 'price': price}
    key = ' '.join(f.strip() for f in fields)
    if key not in yourdata:
        yourdata[key] = [value]
    else:
        yourdata[key].append(value)

print(yourdata)
```

Or why not use a 2 part key...

```
    #  ...

    key = (' '.join(f.strip() for f in fields), title)
    value = {'quantity': quantity, 'price': price}
    yourdata[key] = value

    #  ...
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! and yes I did made a mistake. Thank you for recognizing that!

Comment: How can I print the company and all the movies by them with quantity and price?

Answer (score 0):

To print your results, you can use something like this. I suppose you used yourdata as a dict with the name of the film company as a key

```
for k in yourdata:
    print k            # format it as you need
    for movie in yourdata[k]:
        print ('\t'+movie['title'])
        print ('\t'+str(movie['quantity']))
        print ('\t'+str(movie['price']))
        print
    print
```